# Mail merge multiple rows

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, mail-merge

My table in excel :

```
Joe Smith, 11-1-12, 9-10am
Joe Smith, 11-1-12, 11-12pm
Joe Smith, 11-2-12, 7-8am
Sara Roy, 11-1-12, 9-10am
Sara Roy, 11-1-12, 11-12pm
```

Needed result which should go in mail to each individual:

Joe smith should get a mail for only his data:

```
Joe Smith, 11-1-12, 9-10am
Joe Smith, 11-1-12, 11-12pm
Joe Smith, 11-2-12, 7-8am
```

Sara Roy should get a mail for only her data:

```
Sara Roy, 11-1-12, 9-10am
Sara Roy, 11-1-12, 11-12pm
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Typically users here want to see what you've tried to solve your problem, just so it's clear that you aren't asking "Hey, will someone do my work for me?" If you add a little detail showing what you've tried or what ideas you have but don't know how to implement, you're more likely to get upvotes and answers.

Answer (score -2):

You can refer follow link: 
http://www.genus.biz/?ArticleKey=IDA444FE8AEDDC4DE8#ID9ED67A6A95E44640
Hope to help you!

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Link only answers are likely to end up being useless if your link goes down. Please consider putting the essential parts of the answer in the answer instead

Comment: -1:  Does not work at all.  The link is simply documentation of another software, which does not applies to any version of MS Word.