# Mail Merge | Excel transpose or any other solution

Tags: worksheet-function, mail-merge

i have an excel with 3 columns: domains, clients, email clients
each client can have more than one domain.

I want to mail merge all my clients to make a change in the dns. but i don't want to send 5 emails to client that have 5 domains.

i just thinking of using some advance 'transpose' action to take each domain with the same client name to different column and then i can set the mail merge to send all columns in a list but i don't know how to do it and i'm sure there is a better and simple way to achieve this.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I found this: http://superuser.com/questions/630949/mail-merge-multiple-rows, very similar question but i did not understand the answer

Comment: Do you need help with the mail merge or with the data combination? Are you wanting a VBA solution?